# Why a single Decision Tree algorithm out runs ensemble technique in accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I have used decision tree algorithm on a "wine" dataset and this dataset predicts the quality of the wine on a scale of 1 to 10 where 1 is worst and 10 is best and the sample code is as below

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("wine.csv")
x=data.drop(columns="quality")# x has all the feature columns
y=data.quality# y has the label column
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=355)
dt=DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit(x_train,y_train)
dt.score(x_test,y_test)
```

now I have got an accuracy of 63% now on the same dataset I have used ensemble technique with bagging approach with the same Decision Tree algorithm as the base model and the sample code is as below

```
bagging=BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),n_estimators=100,
                         bootstrap=True,oob_score=True)
bagging.fit(x_train,y_train)
bagging.score(x_test,y_test)
```

surprisingly I got an accuracy of 61% ie., in ensemle approach the accuracy is decreased and my question is why did the accuracy decreased in ensemble method. Ensemble is very good approach when compared to a single Decision Tree algorithm that means accuracy has to be increased when we use ensemble technique but here why the accuracy is decreased

Comment: There can be several reasons. Maybe it's an overfitting. Or the dataset is not representable. Did you try tuning models?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your results. For your code, I achieve 0.94 accuracy for the DecisionTreeClassifier, 0.98 of accuracy for the BaggingClassifier. Here is a link for the [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nvq-sHpWDljUECa7k9lqNKTZ5unffmUd#scrollTo=wM-2kbSyFN7L).

One more point - the size of the dataset is too small to be able to discuss the performance of the ML algorithms.